# Avoiding memory leaks with long expressions that use overloaded operators on heap allocated objects

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm making vector objects and using operator overloading so that they can be added, subtracted etc. easily. At present, my operator functions all calculate a resulting vector and return it. In the case of all vectors, the elements are heap allocated, and this happens in the constructor, so the resultant vector is heap allocated as well. Now I've run into an issue. Suppose I wanted to compute the following (assuming addition and multiplication operator overload functions work as I stated).

```
vector x = vector(3);
vector y = vector(3);
vector z = x + 2*y
delete x;
delete y;
delete z;
```

What should I do for this to not cause a memory leak? As it stands, my code would create a new vector in memory for 2*y and that would just be left there, not being assigned to everything. Is there any alternate approach that would prevent this?
It's possible this doesn't cause a memory leak though I'm not sure how to find that out (new to c++), I'm just assuming it will based off the fact that 2*y allocates memory and isn't deleted.
Below are my definitions for vector addition and scalar multiplication and the constructor.

```
vector(int dim) {
   n=dim;
   vals = new float[n];
}
vector operator + (const vector y) {
    assert(y.n == n); // n is number of elements
    vector z = vector(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        z.vals[i] = vals[i] + y.vals[i]; // vals is a heap allocated array
    }
    return z;
}
vector operator * (const float c) {
    vector z = vector(n)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        z.vals[i] = c*z.vals[i];
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: You only `delete` what you `new`. There is no need for `delete` in any of the code you've shown. Just make sure `vector` obeys the [rule or 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Better yet, make `vals` an `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the constructor for vector, I'll edit it in, but whenever any vector object is created, it's values are made using new, so when z is made in either case, it's constructor will say vals = new float[n]

Comment: Why are you using `new` at all in a program that uses `std::vector`?  Your class just needs to use value semantics -- there is no need for dynamically allocated objects.  Wait - this is your `vector` class?  Well, why are you writing your own, when `std::vector` exists?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That seems to be more of a mathemathical vector  instead of a generic container vector.

Comment: The expression `2*y` should not work. If you had `y * 2`, then that would be equivalent to `y.operator*(2)`, but `2 * y` is equivalent to calling the *global* (non-member) `operator*(2, y)`.

Comment: @sk007 ok, so we need to see whether this vector has correct copy semantics.  Returning it by value as you're doing it now is a non-starter until copying and assigning such objects contains zero bugs.

Comment: Also, you should put your `vector` in a namespace.  Your code will just look confusing, since there is a `std::vector` class.

Comment: Didn't know vector was an in std but I'm just making an object to represent a vector in math and do mathematical operations with it.